# assets:precompile and capistrano run locally but not on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ember.js, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I'm using capistrano to deploy a Rails app to a vps server.

Everything works fine until the last update. When capistrano runs `assets:precompile`, I now get the error:

```
rake aborted!
TypeError: Object function (deps, callback) {
if (Array.isArray(deps)) {
var params = deps.map(function(dep) {
return this.lookup(dep);
}, this);
if (callback) {
callback.apply(null, params);
}
return undefined;
}
else {
return this.lookup(deps);
}
} has no method 'bind'
```

When I run it with `--trace` option I get this:

```
https://gist.github.com/NicosKaralis/5421153#file-cap-deploy
```

It doesn't say where the problem is and when I ran the same command on my local machine it works fine.

My machine is a Max OS X and my server is a Ubuntu 10.10

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

My `application.js`: https://gist.github.com/NicosKaralis/5422877#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: Can we see your `application.js`? Is the code of subject written by you or it appears to be an external library (jquery or similar)?

Comment: Check my edit. I don't think I understand what you asked

Comment: Your `application.js` looks fine. Apart of the topic, it is recommended to separate manifest part from js code. In your case you can move the js routines in a separated js file in `app/assets/javascripts`. I was asking if you can find the javascript code shown in the error message? Or it is a part of some library like jQuery or ember?

Comment: I can't find it anywhere. I opened the page in development mode, where I can see the plain js, and I didn't see this piece of code. I think this is some library code, probably emberjs

Comment: I would suggest to update js libraries. If you rely on `ember-rails` gem , try to update it.

Comment: everything updated. i even removed the bundle folder to remove all old gems, but still giving this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was caused by some old gems on the server.

After i removed everything and started over it is working normally.

Comment: Was there anything else that you did to get this working? I'm experiencing the exact same issue but wiping out old gems hasn't helped

Comment: because my problem was critical i find easier to just wipe the vps and start over, but according to what i found, if you manage to remove all gems and rubies from everywhere and install them again, this should (technically) work

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue. Adding the following line to my `Gemfile` worked for me:

`gem 'therubyracer', require: 'v8'`

Comment: i dont need this gem because my production environment already has nodejs. the problem was something on Gemfile.lock, some gem conflicts

Comment: My server also had node installed but was still running into issues. I added this answer so that it may in some way help other people who land on this question with a related problem.